# Java Quartz Spring transaction support

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, quartz

I need to write a database logic in Quartz job detail bean. Can I do that without any explicit declarations, or how to do that properly to be sure it runs in transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example would be good but I suggest that you simply add `@Transactional` to the method you are running. That should do it.

More info here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Answer (score 0):

So seems that you want to wrap Quartz job execution in a global transaction to comply with some transactional operation to another database.

According to the Quartz documentation [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-11.html), you basically have to:

- Use `JobStoreCMT` or its subclass as Quartz job store (e.g., `LocalDataSourceJobStore` in Spring);
- Set `org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction` to true;
- Manage the transaction in the JTA way in your own code.

Typically, for the last step above, if you are using Spring, you could simply:

- Mark the `job.execute()` with `@Transactional`;
- Chain the two transaction manager (Quartz's and your own database's) together, like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500323/spring-how-to-configure-transactional-properly-with-two-datasources);